# Execute Stored Procedure and get and save xml c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been trying to execute a stored procedure, returning xml, and saving that xml to a file with asp.net c#.  I have tried many things and have used bits and pieces from other posts here on stack overflow.  My procedure works fine when I run it in sql server management studio; however, I cannot seem to get it to right correctly.  The saved file always comes back blank or with one line.  Is there anything I am doing wrong that somebody can see?  I am very amature at doing this and would apreciate any help I can get.  See code below...

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=server\ERP;DataBase=dbase;User ID=id;Password=pw");
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Labels_printer", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@job_control", jobControl));

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@from", from));

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@to", to));

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@factory", 88));

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@printer", printer));
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 1000;
    //System.Xml.XmlReader myXmlReader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader();
    using (XmlReader reader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader()) //e.command.commandtimeout = 500
    {

        while (reader.Read())
        {
          //  string s = reader.ReadOuterXml();


            XmlDocument dom = new XmlDocument();
            dom.Load(reader);

            var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

                using (var writer = XmlTextWriter.Create(@"\\file\.xml", settings))
                {
                    dom.WriteContentTo(writer);



            }
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
```

Comment: To me, it seems you are creating the file over and over again and writing one line each time. Note: (var writer = XmlTextWriter.Create(@"\\file\.xml", settings)) line is inside the while loop, so you will probably get always the last line.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do. Why not use the Entity Framework and just call your Stored Procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move this :
using (var writer = XmlTextWriter.Create(@"\file.xml", settings))
outside of the while.

Comment: Thank you, this was part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
using (XmlReader reader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader()) //e.command.commandtimeout = 500
    {
        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

        using (var writer = XmlTextWriter.Create(@"\\file\.xml", settings))
        {
           while (reader.Read())
           {
            //  string s = reader.ReadOuterXml();


                XmlDocument dom = new XmlDocument();
                dom.Load(reader);
                dom.WriteContentTo(writer);
           }
        }
    reader.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually get XML from the Stored procedure either as a field (Rec.GetString(Rec.GetOrdinal("XMLFieldName")) then load this string into an XMLDocument using dom.LoadXML(strXML).  What I dont understand is why you would want to do that?  Just save the XML string to a text file.  Its the same thing.  You only use XMLDocument if you want to parse it, add/remove nodes, etc..